# Data types vs Data structures

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, types

Is `struct` in C language a data type or a data structure? According to Wikipedia, an array is a composite data type, but isn't an array a data structure? How data structures differ from data types.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a better question for [cs.se] than [so].

Comment: `int` and `float` are data types, but they're not structures. A data structure is a type that can contain multiple values in some organized way.

Comment: Data Structure is how data is organized in memory, Data type specifies the kind of data we store in memory, at the end of day its all bits and bytes, So in a nut shell every data type is also a data structure.

Comment: @IrAM Nice one, but I'd say, every data type _uses_ a certain data structure to store the data.

Comment: The words aren't well-defined like mathemetical definitions. Normally data structure implies some additional logic or constraints for accessing the data that solve a particular problem. An array solves the problem of accessing or mutating elements in O(1) time so is a datastructure. This is in the context of "data structures and algorithms". In day-to-day talk, you might call any old data a data structure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question. From the programmer point of view those terminology nuances make no or very very small difference.

Comment: Data structure is a collection of data values - attay is collection of data values

Comment: @klutt sorry for the inconvenience you had.

Comment: @shehanchanuka No worries at all. I did find the question interesting. Just not suitable here.

Answer (score 1):

[An array is a data type in C, so is a structure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)

A [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) is a way of organizing data, which can use one or more data types.

Answer (score -1):

`struct` is a shot form of 'structure'. They are a way of organizing data. A structure can be created using multiple types of primitive (or complex) member types. For example,

```c
struct EmployeeRecord {
    float mSkillLevel = 1.0f;
    int mWorkingYears = 0;
};
```

An array on the other hand is a collection of records of a similar type. Meaning that the array contains multiple data of just one type. An array will look like this,

```c
EmployeeRecord employees[10];    // Stores records of 10 employees.
int numbers[15];    // Stores 15 numbers.
```

Now arrays are a data structure too. Meaning the above example can be broken down and implemented using `struct` like this,

```c
struct RecordArray10 {
    EmployeeRecord record1;
    EmployeeRecord record2;
    EmployeeRecord record3;
    ...
} employees;

struct NumArray15 {
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    ...
} numbers;
```

Now these have the practical problem of indexing the record. For this we need to cast it to its member type (which is `EmployeeRecord`) pointer and then we can index it,

```c
EmployeeRecord* pArray = (EmployeeRecord*)&numbers;
EmployeeRecord& firstElement = pArray[0];    // Indexing the first element.
```

For the ease of use, C provides the support for arrays directly using the first syntax which I mentioned.

Arrays are of 2 types,

1. Static arrays (which are resolved at compile time and cannot be resized).
2. Dynamic arrays (which can be resized at runtime).

References: 
[Wikipedia: Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) 
[Wikipedia: Array data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) 
[Array vs Data Structure](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-structure-and-array-in-c/)